# Kivy switch launches popup multiple times

Tags: python, popup, widget, kivy

I'm working on a complex piece of code, but have one minor error that I can't seem to solve. When a user toggles a switch, I want a popup to open. After the popup is closed the switch is still on (which is what I want). When the user toggles the switch off, the popup launches again (which is not what I want).

I tried creating some way to simply turn off the switch without pressing it. When I do that the popup still launches. I've been trying to make some conditional statements that only launch the popup when the previous state of the switch was inactive. I'm having some logic issues with that approach. I feel like there should be some setting for the switch that only launches something when it's toggled on. I've searched high and low through the Kivy API but haven't found the answer. I would typically just use a button for this because it would avoid the issue altogether, but I have been asked to use a switch instead of a button so I need to get this to work somehow.

I threw together a quick app that demonstrates the issue that I'm having. Just throw the code in Python and it should run just fine.

```py
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

import os

Builder.load_string("""
<MyWidget>:
    id: my_widget
    Switch
        text: "open"
        on_active: my_widget.launch()
""")


class MyWidget(BoxLayout):

    def launch(self):
        popup_content = BoxLayout()
        example_popup = Popup(
            title='Leeeeeeeeeroyy Jenkins!', content=popup_content)
        popup_content.add_widget(Button(text='cancel', size_hint=(
            None, None), size=(400, 100), on_release=example_popup.dismiss))
        example_popup.open()


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

When you run the code, toggle the switch and a popup will appear. This is what I want. Hit the cancel button and the popup will close. You'll notice that the switch is in the on position. This is what I want. When you toggle the active switch I want it it to just turn to inactive, but you'll notice that it launches the popup again.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check the `active` attribute of the `Switch` in your `on_active:` rule, and only create the `Popup` if `active` is `True`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Builder.load_string("""
<MyWidget>:
    id: my_widget
    Switch
        text: "open"
        on_active: if self.active: my_widget.launch()
""")


class MyWidget(BoxLayout):

    def launch(self):
        popup_content = BoxLayout()
        example_popup = Popup(
            title='Leeeeeeeeeroyy Jenkins!', content=popup_content)
        popup_content.add_widget(Button(text='cancel', size_hint=(
            None, None), size=(400, 100), on_release=example_popup.dismiss))
        example_popup.open()


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```